# How to implement API key pair Authentication/Authorization in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, authentication, authorization, aws-api-gateway

We have our rest API deployed on AWS Lambda behind API Gateway. For users that use our web client, they are authenticated using API Gateway Authorizer through JWT token from Cognito.

Now we want to give users the ability to create their own API credentials (API key and secrets) so that they can use the REST APIs directly without using the web client. How can we achieve that?

Comment: yes you can do it you can use federated identity and make user to signup and they can get their own api key and secrets. you can also change the flow of the cognito as per your need and make new lambda and add it to cognito as trigger.

Comment: Hi, @harshmanvar thanks, please put your comment as an answer and if possible be a little more specific / leave links to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it you can use federated identity and make user to signup and they can get their own api key and secrets. you can also change the flow of the cognito as per your need and make new lambda and add it to cognito as trigger.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html